# JDeveloper error running java program

Tags: java, jboss, jdeveloper

I receive this error in running a Java program within JDeveloper and I have no idea what to do to fix the error:

javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: 160.151.120.33:999

I know I can change the URL and port by changing the values in a jndi.properties file.  I am quite new to Java, JDeveloper, EJB, and JBoss.

This is a desktop app that is failing to connect.  Am I supposed to deploy the EJB to a JBoss server first?  How does the EJB, JBoss and a desktop Java app work and communicate with each other?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is trying to access an EJB then yes you first need to run/deploy the EJB and only then run the client.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - now I know I have to deploy the EJBs in a jar file to the jboss server.  My jboss server is a linux server that I do not have access to, thus I need to make jar files of them and give them to the administrator to place on the jboss 7 server, right?  Do they go in the <JBOSS_HOME>/standalone/deployments folder?

Comment: One option is to run your EJB on the embedded WebLogic in JDeveloper - so open the EJB project in JDeveloper and click to run it. Then run your client project.

Comment: I get the following error when I try to run it:
Error(20,33):  package org.jboss.ejb3.annotation does not exist
Which jar file will include this?

Comment: On this line:
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.TransactionTimeout;